# Android not showing all notifications

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I made an app that can send a lot notifications at the same time, the problem is if the number of notifications is bigger than like 6 or seven not all notifications show up, despite the log saying that all notifications were created and having unique ids.

here is the code of the service for the notifications

```
class GeofenceService : JobIntentService() {

    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {

        if (intent.action == GeofencingConstants.ACTION_GEOFENCE_EVENT) {
            val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)

            if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
                val errorMessage = errorMessage(this, geofencingEvent.errorCode)
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)
                return
            }

            if (geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {
                Log.v(TAG, this.getString(com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes.R.string.geofence_entered))

                val fenceId = when {
                    geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences.isNotEmpty() ->
                        geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences
                    else -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "No Geofence Trigger Found! Abort mission!")
                        return
                    }
                }

                val notificationManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(this, NotificationManager::class.java) as NotificationManager
                notificationManager.handleNotification(this, fenceId)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "geofence-transitions"
        private const val JOB_ID = 573

        fun enqueueWork(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
            enqueueWork(context, GeofenceService::class.java, JOB_ID, intent!!)
        }
    }
```

here the code for the notification generation

```
fun NotificationManager.handleNotification(context: Context, geofences: List<Geofence>){
    val list = ArrayList<Notification>()
    val set = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    val notificationIdBase = (Date().time / 1000L % Int.MAX_VALUE).toInt()
    this.apply {
        for (i in geofences.indices){
            val notificationId = notificationIdBase + i
            val notification = createGroupNotification(context, notificationId, geofences[i].requestId)
            list.add(notification)
            notify(notificationId, notification)
            set.add(notificationId)
            Log.d("TAG", notificationId.toString())
        }

        Log.d("TAG", geofences.size.toString() + " " + list.size + " " + set.size)
        for (id in set){
            Log.d("TAG", id.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

and here the logs for a case with 29 notifications generated but only 24 showed up on the phone.

```
2020-05-04 16:46:32.944 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607192
2020-05-04 16:46:32.948 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607193
2020-05-04 16:46:32.952 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607194
2020-05-04 16:46:32.956 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607195
2020-05-04 16:46:32.958 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607196
2020-05-04 16:46:32.960 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607197
2020-05-04 16:46:32.965 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607198
2020-05-04 16:46:32.968 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607199
2020-05-04 16:46:32.971 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607200
2020-05-04 16:46:32.974 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607201
2020-05-04 16:46:32.977 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607202
2020-05-04 16:46:32.979 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607203
2020-05-04 16:46:32.981 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607204
2020-05-04 16:46:32.983 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607205
2020-05-04 16:46:32.985 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607206
2020-05-04 16:46:32.987 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607207
2020-05-04 16:46:32.990 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607208
2020-05-04 16:46:32.992 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607209
2020-05-04 16:46:32.994 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607210
2020-05-04 16:46:32.996 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607211
2020-05-04 16:46:32.998 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607212
2020-05-04 16:46:33.000 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607213
2020-05-04 16:46:33.002 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607214
2020-05-04 16:46:33.004 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607215
2020-05-04 16:46:33.005 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607216
2020-05-04 16:46:33.008 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607217
2020-05-04 16:46:33.009 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607218
2020-05-04 16:46:33.010 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607219
2020-05-04 16:46:33.012 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 1588607220
2020-05-04 16:46:33.012 31374-31459/com.superapps.ricardo.smithnotes D/TAG: 29 29 29
```

I even tried grouping them in a notification group but even more notifications disappear.

Thanks

Comment: There is a hard limit of 25 notifications per package: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/439ac26e6792b38deff4166dc7c1b35ddce18804/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java#L291 You might consider manually collapsing the information from multiple notifications when they go above a certain count without being cleared. Cancel all the existing ones and send a new one with the combined info for the user.

Comment: the problems comes way before 25, like if i have 12 it shows 11, if I havee 13 it shows 12, 24 shows 21

Comment: Is it happening for one device or all? (in case it is a device specific limitation, good to check on other devices too)

Comment: i tested in 2 real xiaomi devices and the emulator

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by  Tenfoure04 in comments,  there's a hard limit on notificationns per package(https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/439ac26e6792b38deff4166dc7c1b35ddce18804/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java#L291).

Another problem that you might be facing is bundling of notifications by android. Similar notifications might be getting bundled. Just try to decrease the frequency of notifications.

Comment: the problem happens way before the limit. if i have 10 notifications only 9 will the appear. the 1st one wont

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on the android versions above oreo, then you have to use a notification channel for notifications from the notificationManager. I think it will work, as it did in mine.

Comment: cant be that i have a channel

Answer (score 0):

use this code   `Support all Versions`

```
     lateinit var notification: NotificationCompat.Builder
        lateinit var manager: NotificationManager
        val channel = "NotificationTest"
        lateinit var notificationChannel: NotificationChannel


         manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channel, 
             "notification",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
                manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            }

            notification=NotificationCompat.Builder(this,channel)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText("this is for test")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)


    manager.notify(1,notification.build())
```

Comment: cant be that i have a channel